# How to do Multiplication between 2 dataframes based on column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames. The first contains the columns

```py
['Srno', 'Category', 'Category%', 'Total', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Extra']
```

and the second contains the columns

```py
['Srno', 'Category', 'TotalCount']
```

I want to multiply the values in the columns

```py
['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Extra']
```

in the first DataFrame, with the values in the column `Totalcount` in the second DataFrame, based on the `Category` column.

I then want to replace the original values in the columns

```py
['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Extra']
```

with the new values.

---

I have tried the following:

```py
df.columns = ['Srno', 'Category', 'Category%', 'Total', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Extra']

df2.columns = ['Srno', 'Category', 'TotalCount']

for j, k in zip(df2['Totalcount'], df.iloc[:, 4:9]):
    x = j * k
    print(x)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the category column"?

Answer (score 0):

If column `Category` in `df2` has unique categories use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by categories:

```
cols = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Extra']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['Category'].map(df2.set_index('Category')['TotalCount']), axis=0)
```

If possible categories are duplicated remove dupes first:

```
s = df2.drop_duplicates('Category').set_index('Category')['TotalCount']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['Category'].map(s), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```py
cols = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5']
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols] * df2['Totalcount']
```

But I don't understand what you mean by "based on the category".